# Setting up a TTSectionedDataSource

Tags: iphone, sdk, three20

I am trying to create a TTTable with multiple sections. I have everything laid out inside of an array that looks a little something like this.

```
                       @"Styles",
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Styled Views" URL:@"tt://styleTest"],
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Styled Labels" URL:@"tt://styledTextTest"],

                       @"Controls",
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Buttons" URL:@"tt://buttonTest"],
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Tabs" URL:@"tt://tabBarTest"],
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Composers" URL:@"tt://composerTest"],
```

How do I put these values inside of my data source. I've tried:

```
self.dataSource = [TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithArrays:myArray];
```

However that seems to make my application crash.

Answer (score 3):

it would be helpful if you would include the entire assignment statement, e.g.,

```
myArray = ... ;
```

my guess is that the code is missing a ", nil" right before the final "]" in the assignment statement.

Comment: The array is fine its created with a series of for loops that i think would maake the question look more complex then it really is. I am not asking how to create the array because that part is already done properly. I am asking how to move the objects from within that array into self.dataSource.

Comment: in that case, what you want is to put a ", nil" before the "];" in your assignment to self.dataSource - note that the method is called "dataSourceWithArrays" (plural)!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `[TTSectionedDataSource initWithItems:sections:]`, where `items` is an array containing per-section arrays of `TTTableItem`s. E.g.:

```
NSAutoreleasePool* localPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Styles Section
[sections addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Styles", @"Styles")];
NSMutableArray* itemsRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[itemsRow addObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Styled Views" URL:@"tt://styleTest"]];
// Add more 'Styles' rows here...
[items addObject:itemsRow];
TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(itemsRow);

// Controls Section
[sections addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Controls", @"Controls")];
itemsRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[itemsRow addObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Buttons" URL:@"tt://buttonTest"]];
// Add more 'Controls' rows here...
[items addObject:itemsRow];
TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(itemsRow);
TTSectionedDataSource* ds = [[TTSectionedDataSource alloc] initWithItems:items sections:sections];

// Cleanup
TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(items);
TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(sections);
[localPool drain];
```